# Fresh pasta work surface

Tags: pasta, cleaning, cutting-boards

Is there any risk damaging my nice large Boos cutting board to make fresh pasta on?  Each recipe/video/tutorial I see on fresh pasta just says "work surface", but does not mention how to properly clean it afterwards.

I have an oversize plastic board as well, would that work? Would an alternative be to make it directly on my granite countertop?  I love pasta, but don't want to damage anything of value in my kitchen making it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generally make pasta on any surface.  I have seen it on:

- Marble
- Stainless
- Wood

The key issue is having the surface well floured, so that the pasta doesn't stick.

You certainly would not harm a quality wooden cutting board by making pasta, although if your recipe contains raw egg, you will want to wash it well and sanitize it afterwards.